# How to customize the Electron title bar and how to make this as draggable

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am working on a electron project and want to add a custom frame at the top. I wanted to see if someone was aware how to do this? Here is a Screen Shot Mockup up what I want the custom frame to be able to have in it:
[Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YofyO.png)

I also want to be able to put some buttons and selectors in this area. If you can offer any help is achieving any of this please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

```js
      const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
                width: 1200,
                height: 800,
                minWidth: 1200,
                minHeight: 800,
                titleBarStyle: 'hiddenInset',
                frame: false,
                webPreferences: {
                    nodeIntegration: true,
                    devTools: true
                }
            });
```

By setting `titleBarStyle: false` and `frame: false` The native title bar and default buttons will be hidden.

Now you can build the own title bar.

And then to make this draggable you need to use `-webkit-app-region: drag` Add this on your header CSS so that this header will be draggable region.

Comment: Ok thanks i got the bar to work. I just have 1 more question about it. What would i do to make the top bar "draggable" to enable the app to be draggable.

Comment: @FoldedLettuce I've updated anwser. You can check that.

Comment: My pleasure. anytime